# Does missing completely at random and imputing the mean together affect the bias or efficiency of the OLS estimator?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

Suppose I am given a response variable $y$ and two predictors $A$, $B$. The correlations between these variables are given by $\rho_{AB} = 0.4395$, $\rho_{Ay} = 0.3141$, and $\rho_{By} = 0.9587$.

There are $n$ observations and a reasonably large fraction of the observations in column $A$ are missing completely at random (MCAR). I then impute these values using the mean of $A$.

How does this affect $\hat{\beta}$ for a linear regression? Will it become biased or less efficient because of imputing the mean?

Comment: Actually the second regression is not imputed. The default na action for lm in R is na.omit. That is, all rows of data with at least one observation missing are excluded. Since the missingness mechanism is completely at random, the coefficients are unbiased in the second model.

Comment: I fixed the code. When I consolidated my code for my question, I accidentally omitted the line that imputed the mean.